# ImportError : cannon import name 'path' | django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to learn Django and when I tried to run it for the first time, that's the error that I had.

```
PS C:\Users\Alnis\Documents\CS20\lecture3> python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x0000000004067EB8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 124, in 
inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 256, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "C:\Users\Alnis\Documents\CS20\lecture3\lecture3\urls.py", line 17, in <module>
from django.urls import path
ImportError: cannot import name path
```

I tried to update django, but that did nothing.
My Django version :

```
PS C:\Users\Alnis\Documents\CS20\lecture3> django-admin --version
1.11.29
```

**Can somebody help me please ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from your output log I can see you are using python 2.7. When using python 2, pip will install a compatible django version, so version 1.x. Path is only available for django version 2.x which is only compatible with python 3, so if you want to use path you will need to install python 3 and then install django version 2.x.

Comment: Hello, I already have python 3, but when I type "python3 manage.py runserver" nothing starts.

Comment: Regardless if you have python 3 installed, your machine is choosing to use python2.7. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I think I found the problem, I have a x64 system but I have python 2.7(64bits) and Python 3.8(32bits) and I think that's why my system use Python 2 instead of Python 3. I'm gonna uninstall and install a new version of Python. I'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: If you are using pycharm or vscode you will need to point the IDE to the correct interpreter either way. If you do not need python 2, do not install it as it just causes problems and is deprecated.

Comment: @pepitoo999 if I helped can you please select my answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Import this

```
from django.urls import include, re_path

re_path(r'^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
re_path(r'^bio/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.bio, name='bio'),
re_path(r'^weblog/', include('blog.urls')),
```

Instead

```
from django.urls import path
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path.

Comment: You linked docs and referenced features of django 2.0, they are using django 1.11 those features are not available.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

1. Uninstall Pyhton

I had 2 versions of Pyhton, 2.7 and 3.8 but the 3.8 were in x86 so my system always used to use the x64 bits so he cannot find the PATH

2. Install the new version of Python

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-390/

3. Install Django

```
pip install django
```

4. Check your Django version

```
django-admin --version
```

5. Start your app

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Be sure to have **ONLY ONE** version of Python in your machine